# Statement invalid outside Type block - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code which consolidates/ merges all duplicate rows with the same text in columns 1-4 and sums the value in column 5.

The code has been functioning correctly for some time however all of a sudden has stopped working and I am faced with the below error message:

Compile Error:

> Statement invalid outside type block

Any help to resolve this would be much appreciated

```
Sub nSum()
    Dim Rng As Range, Dn As Range, n As Long, Txt As String, Ac As Long
    Set Rng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    ray(1 To Rng.Count, 1 To 4) 'Column count ''***ERROR LINE***************

    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare

        For Each Dn In Rng
            Txt = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Dn.Resize(, 3))), ",")
            If Not .Exists(Txt) Then
                n = n + 1
                For Ac = 1 To 4: ray(n, Ac) = Dn.Offset(, Ac - 1): Next Ac
                .Add Txt, n
            Else
                ray(.Item(Txt), 4) = ray(.Item(Txt), 4) + Dn.Offset(, 3)
            End If
        Next

        n = .Count
    End With

    With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Resize(n, 4)
        .Value = ray
        .Borders.Weight = 2
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub'
```

Comment: What should `ray(1 To Rng.Count, 1 To 4)` do? Probably you meant something like `ReDim ray(1 To Rng.Count, 1 To 4)`?

Comment: Declare your array and turn it around like `Dim ray(1 To 4, 1)` then `ReDim` the array when required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are trying to declare or reinitialize an array called `ray`.

Thus either the word `ReDim` or `Dim` is skipped:

```
Sub nSum()
    Dim Rng As Range, Dn As Range, n As Long, Txt As String, Ac As Long
    Set Rng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Dim ray(1 To Rng.Count, 1 To 4) 'Or Redim Ray(1 To ...
    'Rest of the code
End Sub
```